# Trace32: var.string character limit

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

It seems in t32 var.string() only returns up to 256 characters. This is very limiting when wanting to view large structs. Is there a way to work around this? I am currently trying to use winprint.v.v but that not working very easily.

Comment: I suggest to contact Lauterbach to overcome that 256 character limit. Otherwise please post an example of your struct giving a better chance to come up with a workaround.

Comment: All you need is a struct where the variable names and values are longer than 256 characters.   
I found a better way in the the pdfs. Var.Write <fileno> <HLL expression> which seems limited to 4k characters.

Thanks for your input!